# Bokeh: Time series selection

Tags: python, bokeh

Say I have data plotted for the last 50 years, but then I want to select last month, last year, last 10yrs, etc. I can do this approximately by using a box zoom tool, but is there a way for easier time series selection beyond box zoom?

For example, a slider bar (like google finance) or a radio button group (to select '1M', '1Y') but I want them to be standalone, not served. They are just an improved easy-to-use version of box zoom.

Comment: I am a bit confused about your wording... Do you mean zooming (setting the range of an axis) or are you really talking about selection (marking datapoints as selected). The google finance slider that you are reffering to is a zoom function. Zooming and selcting are two different thing in the bokeh lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use the bokeh server, you have to do it on the client side. This can be done by adding custom tools or widgets in coffeescript (which compiles into javascript)

[This example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions_gallery/widget.html) shows you the direction to go. I made another custom tool for bokeh and from that experience I would recommend you work on the coffeescript side (instead of writing it directly in javascript) since the javascript part of bokeh is still changing quite a bit between releases, the coffee script way might abstract a bit the detail dependencies of the library.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I want... Unfortunately I have no JS or coffeescript knowledge.

Comment: The example shows it... its not too hard. And i think its the only way to do it. Just start with the example code from the bokeh website and do little changes at once...

Comment: Just found that xwheel-zoom does very close to what I need

Comment: @jf328 but it answers your question right? Then it would be nice if you mark it as accepted answer.